# I want to display main page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I deleted the login get route from the web route file because I want to display it on the main page,  but when I visit the HomePage "/" it redirects me to the login Page and it displays an error

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

my routes file

```
Route::get('/', "HomeController@index")->name("main");
// Authentication Routes...
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('register');
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('/password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

How to delete the redirection and I dont want "/login" to work in get method. How to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file in app/Http/Middleware called Authenticate, it redirects the user to the route written in this file, for me it's `return route('login');`. You can change it as you wish.

Comment: thanks, but I now tried using "/" and I got an error: Route [/] not defined.

Comment: Change ```Route::get('/', "HomeController@index")->name("main");``` to ```Route::get('/', "HomeController@index")->name("/");``` or rename your **/** with **main**

Comment: can we see your index function inside your HomeController ?